# Intersection of sets

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to remember what the SQL solution is for this type of problem.  Let's say I have the following tables:

`tagged_nodes`:

1. `nid` - Node id.  Foreign key.
2. `tid` - Tag id.  Foreign key.
3. `tnid` - Primary key (irrelevant to the problem at hand).

`nodes`:

1. `nid` - Node id.  Primary key.
2. ... - Other columns are irrelevant.

Assuming I have a set of tag ids (`tid`), I want to return the set of associated nodes (intersection).  How do I do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So here's what I've come up with:

```
$this->Sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `nodes` `n`
    JOIN `tagged_nodes` `t` ON t.nid=n.nid';

 $i=0;
foreach( $tagids as $tagid ) {
     $t = 't' . $i++;
    $this->Sql .= ' INNER JOIN `tagged_nodes` `'.$t.'` ON '
        .$t'.tid=t.tid WHERE '.$t.'.tid='.$tagid;
}
```

It's in PHP since I need it to be dynamic, but it would basically be the following if I needed, say, only 2 tags (`animals`, `pets`).

```
SELECT * FROM nodes n JOIN tagged_nodes t ON t.nid=n.nid
INNER JOIN tagged_nodes t1 ON t1.tid=t.tid WHERE t1.tid='animals'
INNER JOIN tagged_nodes t2 ON t2.tid=t.tid WHERE t2.tid='pets'
```

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT nodes.* FROM nodes                           /* Load node info */
JOIN tagged_nodes ON tagged_nodes.nid = nodes.nid   /* Match node-tag rows with node rows */
WHERE tagged_nodes.tid IN (1, 2, 3)                 /* Filter using tag relationship */
```

Comment: @Hamster, are you sure you want this? The answer by Hans wouldn't be called an intersection.